# Remove user's Session existance after logout

Tags: php, cookies

While browsing through various user logout functions in PHP, I always come across `session_destory()` to remote session variables for a particular use, but they dont use `setCookie()` to remove the user's PHP `SESSIONID`

**The PHP Documentation clearly states:**

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

I tried tracking the cookie in Firefox, and using `session_destroy()`, continues to keep the cookie of PHP `SESSIONID`, the next time the user logs in, the same `SESSIONID` id used.

Isn't it always safe to remote the session id Cookie from the user's machine after he has logged out and also what would happen if I fail to delete the SessionID Cookie?

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

That way the session is empty.

No need (nor added security) by destroying it like you try.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
session_regenerate_id ( true );
```

Description of function:

[session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) — Update the current session id with a newly generated one.
It's only parameter, which is false by default: delete_old_session - Whether to delete the old associated session file or not.